# Intellij: Can I set a default scope on the Hierarchy tab? (Default = "all", I want "Production")

Tags: intellij-idea

I very often use the "Call Hierarchy" shortcut, showing me the call hierarchy of a certain method, so I know where/how often a method gets called.

[image]

Unfortunately the default scope is set to "All", which means that I also get listed all the test methods of any unit test calling this method:

[image]

[image]

For what I want to find out, I never need to know the calls from unit tests (If I would, I'd change the scope). So I want to always only search in production scope.
Is there a way to somewhere state this? I couldn't find any setting for this.